# Rails gem with javascript files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to create a ruby gem for rails out of a plugin I've created.  The problem is that my plugin 'shortcuts' uses a few javascript files which need to be in the public/javascripts directory to work.

What's the best way to make these javascript files which are in the gem I've created accessible by which ever project requires my gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Add a rails generator** to your gem such that `script/generate <yourgem>` puts the javascript files in the correct location.

For more information, see the [How to Make a Generator](http://railscasts.com/episodes/58-how-to-make-a-generator) Railscast.

As an example, the [formtastic gem](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) has a generator that puts its specific stylesheets in the correct location -- similar to your javascript problem.

Another example, [nifty-generators](http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/) is just a gem with useful generators.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy them over by making a `postinstall.rb` which will be automatically executed after your plugin is installed.

Comment: He's turning the plugin into a gem.  No postinstall.